# Call to a member function bundle() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\Condition\EntityBundle->evaluate()

Tags: entities

I have a dev site built on Drupal 9.1.9 and now I'm trying to use the site in 9.3.9. Everything is fully functional on 9.1.9 but when I try to run the same site on 9.3.9 I get. I believe the error is being generated from the context module somehow and I tried disabling each context rule and am still facing the error.

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Call to a member function bundle() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\Condition\EntityBundle->evaluate() (line 93 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Plugin/Condition/EntityBundle.php).

Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\Condition\EntityBundle->evaluate() (Line: 77)
Drupal\Core\Condition\ConditionManager->execute(Object) (Line: 84)
Drupal\Core\Condition\ConditionPluginBase->execute() (Line: 26)
Drupal\context\ContextManager->resolveConditions(Object, 'or') (Line: 352)
Drupal\context\ContextManager->evaluateContextConditions(Object) (Line: 254)
Drupal\context\ContextManager->evaluateContexts() (Line: 242)
Drupal\context\ContextManager->getActiveContexts() (Line: 274)
Drupal\context\ContextManager->getActiveReactions() (Line: 44)
Drupal\context\EventSubscriber\BlockPageDisplayVariantSubscriber->onSelectPageDisplayVariant(Object, 'render.page_display_variant.select', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'render.page_display_variant.select', Object) (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'render.page_display_variant.select') (Line: 224)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 132)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.view') (Line: 163)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

> core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Plugin/Condition/EntityBundle.php
> Once, I made changes to evaluate function by providing if condition on the $entity, then it works as expected. I'm not confident that this approach is the correct way to fix the issue here.

```
public function evaluate() {
    // Returns true if no bundles are selected and negate option is disabled.
    if (empty($this->configuration['bundles']) && !$this->isNegated()) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface $entity */
    $entity = $this->getContextValue($this->getDerivativeId());
    //var_dump($entity); die();
    if($entity){
      return !empty($this->configuration['bundles'][$entity->bundle()]);
    }
  }
```

Should I be looking for the patches here or is there any way I can debug what's causing this error? Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First, check that your modules are up-to-date, that you have run all database updates, and that you have rebuilt the caches.  Then, if you are still having trouble, try switching to the dev branch of Context.  Don't start looking for patches or hacking the code until you are absolutely sure you have updated things properly.

Answer (score 0):

The generic entity bundle condition was introduced in Drupal 9.3. See the change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2983299

This error is usually caused by a context mapping in config. This can also happen in the standard block layout without the context module.

What is the entity type if you var_dump `$this->getDerivativeId()`? This could lead to a context rule like in this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/context/issues/3260611

Comment: `var_dump($this->getDerivativeId(), $entity); ` provides `string(13) "taxonomy_term" NULL ` output. Now, I'm just looking a  way to find out which entity doesn't have taxonomy term. Is there any way to pinpoint the cause

Comment: Export the configuration (via UI or drush cex) and look for a context rule containing the condition `entity_bundle:taxonomy_term`. Then add the context mapping according to the linked issue and import the config again.